# Jquery lightgallery howto turn off captions

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to turn off the caption under the image but I still get the alt-image text as a caption even though I set the caption to false. Any idea how to turn off the captions completely?

`<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { 
   lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery'),{
    getCaptionFromTitleOrAlt: false
   })
});
</script>`

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 item img-gallery center-images-tattoo image-box" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/Piercing/IMG_1825.jpg" >
          <a href="#"><img data-src="images/Piercing/IMG_1825.jpg" src="images/Piercing/thumb/IMG_1825.jpg" alt="Piercing-image" class="img-fluid img-resize2 b-lazy"></a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about lightGallery but why don't you just target some class that is on all images and replace alt parameter with nothing.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $(".img-fluid").attr('alt', "");
});
```

```js
$('img').on({'click': function(){
var alt = this.alt;
  $(".img-fluid").attr('alt', "");  
console.log(alt);
}});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 item img-gallery center-images-tattoo image-box" data-aos="fade" data-src="images/Piercing/IMG_1825.jpg" >
              <a href="#"><img data-src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-0WxzB-qyKSs/XdmpIXv34LI/AAAAAAACc90/JDdlVwUQrGQQAVVflz1WkfPxTDZa1f81wCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/Baby_Yoda_coloring.filminspector.com_3.jpg" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-0WxzB-qyKSs/XdmpIXv34LI/AAAAAAACc90/JDdlVwUQrGQQAVVflz1WkfPxTDZa1f81wCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/Baby_Yoda_coloring.filminspector.com_3.jpg" alt="Piercing-image" class="img-fluid img-resize2 b-lazy" style="max-width:200px"></a>
            </div>
```

As seen above just click twice you'll see alt is gone.